# Remove the shadow effect on windows WINAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, shadow

Is there a way I can remove the drop shadow effect on a window in my program? 
I'm using the Win32 API under VC++, Platform: Windows 10.

I know I can use `SystemParametersInfo()` with `SPI_SETDROPSHADOW` to set it as `FALSE` but I was wondering if there is an option to only affect a single window as this affects all windows?

This shows the shadow that shall be removed (no CS_DROPSHADOW used):
[image: CS_DROPSHADOW not used]

This shows the shadow that is visible if `CS_DROPSHADOW` is used:
[image: CS_DROPSHADOW used]

`SystemParametersInfo()` with `SPI_SETDROPSHADOW` turns off both shadows, but there does not seem to be a windows style or windows class style to disable the shadow that is drawn when `CS_DROPSHADOW` is not used.

Comment: You could set up a [WinEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) hook, and remove the `CS_DROPSHADOW` class style ([SetClassLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633589.aspx)) on creation. I believe this changes all windows of that class in the calling process, though. Better than a system-global solution, but not fine-grained enough to change a single window.

Comment: @IInspectable I just tried this and it seems that CS_DROPSHADOW and SPI_SETDROPSHADOW are both refering to different shadow effects, CS_DROPSHADOW turned on/off something completely different that isn't a problem. so no luck :/

Comment: Hmm, no `CS_DROPSHADOW` is controlled by `SPI_SETDROPSHADOW`. The latter globally enables/disables the former, which is set for individual window classes. Notice that I said individual window *classes*, not windows. This affects all windows of a particular class. That may not be a problem, though. Are you creating these windows yourself? If so, just register a different class. We need more details about what problem you're trying to solve and what your exact situation is.

Comment: `CS_DROPSHADOW` gives you the shadow effect on e.g. a popup menu. To me it sounds like you want to turn off the shadow that **every** overlapped window has on Windows 10. That's something the DWM does itself, I'm not sure if that can be disabled.

Comment: That shadow will always be present if caption bar is not hidden, for instance if you override WM_NCCALCSIZE and modify Msg.CalcSize_Params.rgrc[0].Top value by reducing GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION), it will remove caption bar and the shadow will disappear, similar to BsNone=0 border style but it will keep aero snap features for that window, and you will still need to add a custom caption bar, though custom NCCalcSize it's not recommended since you will end up fixing its size on fullscreen, snap, glitches on resize, etc.