# Delphi remove form shadow

Tags: forms, delphi

I use delphi berlin, I have a main form and I open other forms from the main menu on my main form, I don't use MDI forms

I want to disable form's shadow on the child forms (which I open from the menu on the main form so i call them child formals but they are not MDI Childs)

Can I disable/remove shadow from the form/forms that I choose to remove/disable shadow

I found and have tried removing shadows by using system info API but then I realize what it did was to disable shadows on all windows which are not useful for me, I want to be able to remove/hide shadow from the forms I chose in my application

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's any need to remove shadows via WinAPI calls. You should show us your code for creating and showing the "child" forms. I assume you just missed something there.

Comment: Include CS_DROPSHADOW to the main form class, the others might look less shadowy. :P Or remove them borders from childs :P

Comment: Dupe (with no answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531327/remove-the-shadow-effect-on-windows-winapi

Comment: @SertacAkyuz hi serdar, i checked the link too you gave and i searched google but coudnt find any answer

Comment: @ita - That's why I wrote "with no answer", there's no answer.