# how to remove dropshadow in form?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

How to remove dropshadow effect which is enabled by CS_DropShadow because, shadow is always showing,

below is my code,

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
   get
   {                
       CreateParams value = base.CreateParams;
       value.ExStyle |= WindowMessages.WS_EX_TOPMOST;
       if (this.ShowShadow)
          value.ClassStyle |= WindowMessages.CS_DROPSHADOW;
       else
          value.ClassStyle &= ~WindowMessages.CS_DROPSHADOW;


       return value;
   }
}
```

Help me resolve this.

Comment: You want `value.ClassStyle &= ~(WindowMessages.CS_DROPSHADOW)` in your `else` branch.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe-  but the shadow is not removed still

Comment: You added it to the `else` branch? Then you need to include that code in the question.

Comment: i have added it in else

Comment: what else should i code?

Comment: get
{                
    CreateParams value = base.CreateParams;
    value.ExStyle |= WindowMessages.WS_EX_TOPMOST;
    if (this.ShowShadow)
        value.ClassStyle |= WindowMessages.CS_DROPSHADOW;
    else
        value.ClassStyle &= ~WindowMessages.CS_DROPSHADOW;
    return value;
}

Comment: This might not be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38531327/8446

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143505/discussion-between-amal-and-roger-lipscombe).

Comment: @RogerLipscombe - after disabling the ShowShadow , create params are not called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to disable shadow at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806904/how-to-disable-shadow-at-runtime)

Comment: working with single instance of form doesn't work for shadow. So i have created new instance for this case, and it is working