# how to disable shadow at runtime?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have subclassed form for my requirements and enable shadow with below codes,

```
bool showShadow=true;

public bool ShowShadow
{ 
    get{ return showShadow;}
    set{showShadow= value;}
}

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{ 
   get
   {                
      CreateParams value = base.CreateParams;
      value.ExStyle |= WindowMessages.WS_EX_TOPMOST;
      if (this.ShowShadow)
         value.ClassStyle |= WindowMessages.CS_DROPSHADOW;
      return value;
   }
}
```

I have shown the customized form just by creating single instance through below code,

```
MyForm myform= new MyForm();
myForm.Visible= true;
```

and hided it through myform.Visible = false;

and i disables the shadow for the form, but the shadow is drawing  since the CreateParams is not updated with disabled shadow.

Does anyone know, how to invoke CreateParams for a single instance of form while changing the ShowShadow property at runtime?

Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to P/Invoke with `SetWindowLong` when the value is changed.

Comment: How to use SetWindowLong